# Why after executing function, the address of my pointer change

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, variable-assignment

Here is my code. I want to copy data from a memory region to other memory region. To avoid overlap data i make the order copy, not from the lsb , but from msb of the array like the picture [order of copy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdbiN.png)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdint.h>
void MemCopy2(uint8_t * Src, uint8_t * Dest, uint32_t Len)
{   
    uint32_t count;

    for (count = Len; count > 0; count--)
    {
        Dest[count-1] = Src[count-1];
    }

}

int main()
{

    uint32_t A[2] = { 0xABCD1234, 0x567890AB };
    uint32_t * Ptr = (uint16_t*)&A + 1;  // CD 
    
    printf("%d \n", Ptr);
    
    MemCopy2((uint8_t*)&A, (uint8_t*)Ptr, sizeof(A));

    printf("%d \n", Ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

I printf before and after executing the function `MemCopy2`, the result is

```
6487570 
6444664
```

which means that the value of pointer `Ptr` has been changed

Still this code, if I add a local variable like `int i=6;` before initialize array `A[2]` in main() , now the result is

```
6487554 
6487554
```

which means that the value of pointer `Ptr` remain,
Anyone know why this happen
I think it because of stacking and unstacking to store local variable in register, something like that.

Comment: Why did you add `1` to the `Ptr` assignment? You've told the function to exceed the memory allocation of `A[]`.

Comment: Don't use `%d` to print pointers, it causes undefined behavior.  Cast them to `void *` and use `%p`.

Comment: `Ptr` is located right after `A` in memory. When you wrote outside the bounds of `A`, it modified `Ptr`.

Comment: ...by adding `1` in `(uint16_t*)&A + 1` you actually add `2` bytes – the size of `uint16_t`.

Comment: I add 1 to the Ptr assignment because i want it to point at the address of byte which value is "CD" of array A[], not the first 16 bit. 
No it's not exceed the memory allocation of A[] because i use (uint16_t*)&A . I don't think the code wrong here

Comment: The function is going to copy `sizeof(A)` bytes, but the destination `Ptr` is 2 bytes beyond where `A` begins. So you overflow the array by 2 bytes, corrupting something else.

Comment: @OP why are you arguing about this? Just run it with valgrind or an address sanitizer. It's not a matter of opinion, just arithmetic, so get the computer to check it for you

Comment: @NguyễnMinhTiến `uint32_t * Ptr = (uint16_t*)&A + 1;` invokes undefined behavior as it [violates strict aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule).  You can't treat an object as something it's not.  `A` is not a `uint16_t` array, trying to treat it as one violates the strict aliasing rule.  Also, if you believe `CD` is the second byte of the `uint32_t` value at `A[0]`, you'd need to ensure the endianness of your system first....

Comment: You got a couple of good answers.  Make sure you accept the best by clicking on the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the minimal example that includes the missing headers, use `%p` to print addresses, and resolve warnings:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void MemCopy2(const uint8_t *Src, uint8_t *Dest, uint32_t Len) {
    for (uint32_t count = Len; count > 0; count--)
        Dest[count-1] = Src[count-1];

}

int main(void) {
    uint32_t A[2] = { 0xABCD1234, 0x567890AB };
    uint32_t *Ptr = (uint32_t *) ((uint16_t *) &A + 1);
    printf("%p\n", Ptr);
    MemCopy2((uint8_t*)&A, (uint8_t*)Ptr, sizeof(A));
    printf("%p\n", Ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

and the output is:

```
0x7ffeaf38ae82
0x7ffeaf385678
```

The problem is that you copy `sizeof(A)` bytes into a non-zero offset of `A` which will cause a buffer overflow.  As the offset `1` is `sizeof(uint16_t) * 1` i.e. 2 bytes, but you only trail by 1 byte in `MemCopy2()`.  This is undefined behavior and our systems it happens to overwrite `Ptr`.  The technical fix is to 2 byte less, i.e.:

Accessing your array `uin32_t A[]` via a `uint16_t *` is undefined behavior per 6.3.2.3p7. On some platforms it will cause a bus violation and crash the program.  On others like amd64 it's a performance overhead.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define OFFSET 1

void MemCopy2(const uint8_t * Src, uint8_t * Dest, uint32_t Len) {
    for (uint32_t count = Len; count > 0; count--)
        Dest[count-OFFSET] = Src[count-OFFSET];

}

int main(void) {
    uint32_t A[2] = { 0xABCD1234, 0x567890AB };
    uint32_t *Ptr = (uint32_t *) ((char *) A + sizeof(uint16_t) * OFFSET);
    printf("%p\n", Ptr);
    MemCopy2((uint8_t*)&A, (uint8_t*)Ptr, sizeof(A) - sizeof(uint16_t) * OFFSET);
    printf("%p\n", Ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

The interface is clunky, though, maybe move the offset business into `MemCopy2()` to avoid coupling of `OFFSET` in both `MemCopy2()` and `main()`?

Comment: Laundering the address through a `uint16_t *` pointer doesn't only risk an alignment violation.  `uint32_t *Ptr = (uint32_t *) ((uint16_t *) &A + 1);` is undefined behavior on all platforms as it's a [strict aliasing violation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule).

Comment: @AndrewHenle Thanks.  I knew it was iffy but couldn't think of the reason.

Comment: The coding style of just forcing pointer types like that is irksome.  It appears to work fine most of the time on most common platforms.  So when it does blow up, the bug is almost impossible to find, or if they're lucky enough to be on a platform that has alignment restrictions and they happen to trigger it, they get surprised that what they've been taught is all wrong.  Just Google "SIGBUS SPARC" or "SIGBUS ARM".

Comment: @AndrewHenle I tweaked the answer via `char *` which should be ok, right?  Not sure if comment was pre or post that change.   Yeah, I spend a little time on Sparc and it was glorious :-)

Comment: The strict aliasing issue is more subtle.  It would be illegal to access `A` via a `uint16_t *`, i.e. by accessing an lvalue of type `uint16_t`, but the program doesn't actually do that.  Nowhere is a `uint16_t *` actually dereferenced.  What does happen inside `MemCopy2` is that `A` is accessed via an lvalue of type `uint8_t`.  Now that is also technically illegal, but not if `uint8_t` is typedef'd to `unsigned char` which is true for the vast majority of platforms.  Character types are granted a special exemption from the strict aliasing rules, exactly so that things like byte copy can work.

Comment: But by that technicality your version is also (potentially) illegal.  To be 100% safe, the copying in `MemCopy2` really needs to be done via `unsigned char *` and not `uint8_t *`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: The problem with the line of code you cite is not strict aliasing.  Casting a `uint32_t *` to a `uint16_t *` is perfectly legal as long as you do not dereference the resulting pointer before casting it back.  The problem is that `((uint16_t *) &A + 1)` is (most likely) not properly aligned for `uint32_t`, and so casting it back to `uint32_t *` violates 6.3.2.3p7 and causes UB.

Answer (score 1):

As noted (but with some push-back from yourself), you're writing past the end of the `A` variable... consider the following (if I may assume the endianness of your system):

[image: a visual representation of the memory layout, pointer, and lengths]

"*`A` plus 8 bytes*" is the end of the green box... but "*`*Ptr` plus 8 bytes*" is two bytes past the end (i.e: the red mystery box).

In your situation, you're "*lucky*" enough, that the red box happens to hold some of the `Ptr` value.

Comment: *I suggest using either `(uint16_t*)&(A[1])` or `&(((uint16_t*)A)[1])` to be clear with your intent.*  They'd all be wrong, too.  See my comment on the other answer.  All those alternatives would all be [strict aliasing violations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule) and therefore undefined behavior.  You can't treat an object as something it's not without invoking undefined behavior, with the only exception being you can always treat any object as an array of `[[un]signed] char`.

Comment: Good to know - thanks! I've removed it from my answer. (I've always been a bit hazy on that one / sorry I didn't see it in your comments)

Comment: i get your point, i know it risk to use pointer like that, i just want to test to know more about memory allocation.  Besides, still this code, if I add a local variable like int i=6; before initialize array A[2] in main(), the Ptr will remain the same, do you know why is that, it make me think about stacking and unstacking process

Comment: "_if I add a local variable like int i=6; before initialize array A[2] in main(), the Ptr will remain the same_" - it could be to do with alignment (and therefore gaps inserted into the stack between variables), or it could be because the new `i` is being written over instead of the `Ptr`... it's difficult to say without more details about what you're doing and what platform you're using.